# Is this basic for python programming?

Tags: python

I used this:

```
f=open('mark.txt','r')
print f.read()
```

Output:

```
Name;age;year
Mark;19;3rd Year
```

How can I use python to replace above so that the output would be:

```
Name     Age        Year
Mark     19     3rd Year
```

I found this code below in this site but how can I run an output? The output that comes out is just blank.

```
f1=open('mark.txt','r')
f2=open('mark.txt.tmp','w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace(';','\t'))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: The output is blank but the code should create a file named `cities.txt.tmp` with the result.

Comment: sorry, i edited that already... Thank you! :( still blank

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle data files is in my opinion to use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

#### Write output to file

```
import csv

with open('mark.txt', 'rb') as data_file, open('output.txt', 'wb') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(list(reader))
```

#### Replace `;` by `\t` in your file:

```
import csv
import shutil

with open('mark.txt', 'rb') as data_file, open('mark.txt.tmp', 'rb') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(list(reader))

shutil.move('mark.txt.tmp', 'mark.txt')
```

#### Print the file contents with `;` replaced by `\t`:

```
import csv

with open('mark.txt', 'rb') as data_file:
    reader = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print '\t'.join(row)
        #print('\t'.join(row)) in Python 3
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a beginner at this so I think I should study more on some terms or built in functions.

Comment: This is heavy artillery. But it has the advantage of not changing  `;` that are not delimiters (assuming you have data such as `"Mark;John";19;3rd Year` )

Comment: @damienfrancois I see no point in _not_ using csv. It's lightweight, not a lot of extra code, handles special cases like you mention here, and is more robust and maintainable if the input changes in the future.

Comment: Ma'am Steinar, can I email you my program and have a look at it? Thanks

Comment: How about the caps? age and year have capital letters on the output. Is the process the same?

Comment: @user3178623 If you have more questions, feel free to post them as new questions here on SO. I'd rather not post my email-address here - hope that is ok :)

Comment: Regarding caps: The output will be identical to the input data. Did that answer your question? Please update your problem description if it didn't, and I'll have a look at it

Comment: (I updated my answer because I'd forgotten to write `open` two places)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('mark.txt') as in_file, open('mark.txt.tmp', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        out_file.write('\t'.join(line.split(';')))
```

Comment: you can open them both in one with statement to avoid nesting

Comment: What is the advantage of using an intermediate list to simply perform search and replace in a string?

Comment: `with open('mark.txt') as f_in, open('mark.txt.tmp', 'w') as f_out:`

Comment: @win ok ok, if you insist :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
f=open('mark.txt','r')
for line in f.read():
    print line.replace(';', '\t')
f.close()
```

Comment: Is this still basic for python programming sir?

Comment: It's basic file IO so I would say so. File needs to be closed but other than that...

Comment: dangling file handle, redundant mode `'r'`

Comment: welcome and Please vote up and accept the ans, if you this helped you